# Gnu make - how to handle sources from outside my project tree

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

Using:

- Linux as build host (kubuntu 14.04)
- Gnu make 3.81
- Compiling some C/C++ projects

I have a directory tree like this:

- Repository/

  - Framework/

    - Source/

      - Subdir1/
      - Subdir2/

        - Subdir3/
      - et cetera
    - something more
  - Projects/

    - Project1/

      - Source/

        - SubdirA/
        - SubdirB/

          - SubdirX/
        - et cetera
      - Out/            ← subdirs structure below Out/ is for example

        - Source/

          - SubdirA/
          - SubdirB/

            - SubdirX/
        - Framework/

          - Source/

            - Subdir1/
            - Subdir2/

              - Subdir3/
      - Makefile
    - Project2/

      - Source/

        - ...
      - Out/

        - ...
      - Makefile
    - et cetera

The content of the Framework/Source directory is just a connection of some general purpose source files which will be used in a couple of projects. The Framework directory has no own makefile and e.g. won't build a lib. It's just, that the projects uses some of the sourcecode from the Framework directory.

When building Project1, I first cd into the related projects dir and then calling make, e.g.:

```
cd ~/Repository/Projects/Project1
make
```

And all build output has to be put into Project1/Out directory.
Below the Out directory, my makefile mirrors the directory hierarchy from the source tree(s).

Within my makefile, I do something like this:

```
SRCS += $(shell find Source -name "*.c")
SRCS += $(shell find ../../Framework/Source -name "*.c")
BUILDDIR := Out
OBJS = $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(SRCS))))
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

and this causes the problem that during the pattern rule and the ../.. part, some of the generated object files will be placed outside of my build output directory, e.g.:

```
gcc -c ../../Framework/Source/*.c -o Out/../../Framework/Source/*.o
```

My first approach was, to force all source filenames to absolute path names like this:

```
OBJS = $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(abspath $(SRCS)))))
```

This works (even with realpath), but it makes my build output quite ugly because of the long path + filename outputs.

I have a second approach, were I just substitute all `../` parts of the .o files with something like `up/` and it looks like this:

```
OBJS = $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(subst ../,up/,$(basename $(SRCS)))))
```

but then it unfortunately seems. that I have to duplicate all my pattern rules like:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
$(BUILDDIR)/up/up/%.o : ../../%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

So, I'm still looking for a slightly nicer solution for this problem.

For some reasons, I have the following restrictions:

- no symlinks
- no recursive make calls
- no use of vpath
- no libs
- no git submodules ...

Any suggestions for a bit more elegant approach?

Comment: Would it cause a problem to put a separate makefile in the `Out/` directory, so that you could move the `$(BUILDDIR)/%.o` to that separate makefile?

Comment: My `Out/` is part of `.gitignore` and so cannot be shared within my team (and it's also completely cleared during `make cleanall`).

Comment: when you say "Below the Out directory, my makefile mirrors the directory hierarchy from the source tree(s).", what exactly do you mean?  List top level subdirectories below Out so I can understand what you want there.

Comment: Are there any subdirectories in `Framework/Source/`?

Comment: @Beta: Yes, there ist some subdirectory structure below Framework/Source and also below each ProjectX/Source

Comment: @Mark Galeck: I'd edit the question and gave an idea how the struction below `Out/` could be. In my current solution, there was no `Out/Framework/Source` but a `Out/up/up/Framework/Source` instead and that's also ok.

Comment: take a look at my solution I think you will either like it or adapt it to your needs

Comment: @Joe I see what you edited.  Now it is clear.  Let me change my solution to match what you want.  Hold on.

Comment: All this could have been made nicer if you would use vpath. Then you would need a single `%.o: %.c` rule and all the object files would end up in one place, with make finding the sources for you :)

Comment: I'd decided to prevent the use of vpath because of some disadvantages. E.g. in projects with both c and c++ sources, vpath could lead sometimes to confusion. And there is also a problem when using the same filename in different subdirectories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
COLLAPSED_SRC_PREFIXES_IN_BLD := ../../

SRCS += $(shell find Source -name "*.c")
SRCS += $(shell find ../../Framework/Source -name "*.c")

BUILDDIR := Out

.PRECIOUS: %/.
%/.:
    mkdir -p $@


define BLD_FROM_TO

$2/%.o: $1%.c Makefile | $$$$(@D)/.
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $$< $$@

endef


.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(foreach prefix, $(COLLAPSED_SRC_PREFIXES_IN_BLD), $(eval $(call BLD_FROM_TO,$(prefix), $(BUILDDIR))))
$(eval $(call BLD_FROM_TO,, $(BUILDDIR)))
```

Comment: In meanwhile, I'd substituted `$(wildcard ...)` against `$(shell find ...)` to show how I do recursively collect all sources to build.

Comment: yes, I also don't like $(shell find)  :)  Please do not be offended, you ask the question, not me.  It's fine.  I prefer to list the sources _explicitly_.  Otherwise, one sunny day one of your users, is going to put a temporary file in there, that they do not intend to build, and hell will break loose.  I always have them declare what they want explicitly.

Comment: Your suggestion looks interesting and I'll give it a try right now.

Comment: Here you are, it is current to your current question

Comment: Sorry I forgot to edit out the placeholders for CC and flags.  there you go.

Comment: Yep, I got it work now. Nice trick to duplicate the rule using [`define` / `endef`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multi_002dLine.html). But it seems that I don't need that [`.SECONDEXPANSION:`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html#Secondary-Expansion) (am a bit aware of `.SECONDEXPANSION:` cause it seems to have an impact of all other that follows in the makefile, isn't it?). What would you suggest on how to to generate the list of `.o` files (`OBJS = …`)?

Comment: @Joe `.SECONDEXPANSION` is necessary to correctly expand `$$$$(@D)`.  My method makes the directory tree for you automatically as needed.  If you have your directory tree already, yes, it will still work if you delete `.SECONDEXPANSION`.  But if you start clean, your directories won't be made, unless you use it.  The precise effect of `$$` on `@D` on prerequisite line is actually undocumented, but confirmed by the maintainer of GNU Make.

Comment: Well thanks for the clarification about the need of `.SECONDEXPANSION` in the above approach. Yes, I don't use `mkdir` in that above described way. Instead, I'd placed a `@mkdir -p $$(@D)/.` in the line above `$(CC) …`

Comment: @Joe Your modification is less "Make-matic", but given that the feature I am using is not documented, maybe your approach is slightly better.  In that case indeed you don't need .SECONDEXPANSION.  You also don't need the `/.`.  But I would avoid using `@` in your approach.  It is best to show the user what is happening.  If they don't like it, they can filter it out themselves.  That is what shell filters are for.

Comment: @Joe Oh I see, you want the `@` so that `mkdir` it is not printed all the time when most of the time is not needed.  Well, that is the peril of your approach :)  Forgive me then, I am changing my mind about your approach being slightly better :)  for this reason.

Comment: Could you add `OBJS = …` to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

My original answer is preserved below for reference, but the consensus of discussion seems to be that my answer is wrong.  When you have been around long enough, as I have, there is a certain "ring of truth" you can hear in certain criticism.  One just ignores criticism that lacks the ring of truth, but this criticism has that ring.

The odd thing is that I have been using recursive Make for years in my own work, in a properly refactored manner (so that I do not, in effect, keep multiple instances of more or less the same rule) with the help of `include` and symlinks to makefiles (and of course by letting my compiler automatically emit the header dependencies), and it all seems to work fine for me.  It is not easy to set up, and there is some hassle whenever I open a new source subdirectory; but then I had believed that Make with multiple source directories just wasn't going to be easy to set up, so there I am.

I do not know whether the OP has learned what he had sought to learn today, but I seem to have learned something.

I withdraw my answer.  Thank you for having read my answer and having commented on it.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Makefiles always seem to be hard.  There is no definite, unalterable rule, but there are some practices that help.

1. In general, a file is best made by a makefile, not in the directory of the file's prerequisites, *but in the directory in which the file is to be made.*  Thus, you can use several makefiles, one in each directory in which files are to be made.  In your example, for instance, you can put a makefile in the `Out/` directory, then move the `$(BUILDDIR)/%.o:` rule over to that makefile.
2. If you do not know it already, learn Make's `-C` option, and start using it extensively and consistently.  There is nothing wrong with your `cd ~/Repository/Projects/Project1` before `make`, exactly, unless the reason for the `cd` is that you didn't think to use `-C`, instead.  Consistent use of `-C`, both on the command line and within makefile rules, eventually leads you *to think* in a more productive way about makefiles.  It gradually clarifies your perception in the matter, which is good.
3. Also if you do not know it already, learn the use of Make's `$(MAKE)`, for recursive invocation of Make.
4. Use `$(MAKE)` and `-C` together in your rules.

How exactly you assemble these elements into a solution that works for you depends on the details of what you want to do, but the above advice will tend to keep you from fighting Make's design philosophy.  Not fighting will make things easier for you.  Since Make's manual explains features, but does not explain the design philosophy underlying the features very well, this is important.

One could write whole chapters in the matter, so I'll stop here; but if there is a specific point upon which you would like me to expand, feel free to let me know.

Comment: In case you aren't aware there is a fairly well known paper titled [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) which goes into a good amount of detail about just why recursive make is a bad idea and actively hurts the ability of make to do its job well and correctly.

Comment: @EtanReisner:  Thank you for reminding me about that paper.  I had read it years ago, but had forgotten about it.  The paper's suggestions do not really correspond with my own experience, but they do present a point of view readers should consider.  I admit that I do not use parallel Make, which was one of the paper's justifications, so maybe the paper has a point.

Comment: You don't need to try to use make's parallel building capabilities to have its problems with recursive make. Simply have files/rules in one directory depend on built objects from another directory and try to build the former first. Unless you've manually accounted for the deficiencies of recursive make (which is likely possible but probably requires a good bit of work to get functioning by target name) it doesn't work.

Comment: @EtanReisner:  Well, it works for me.  Ironically, one of the paper's principal suggestions is liberally to use Make's `include` directive to avoid makefile recursion.  One can do so, but Make's `include` directive works even better (in my experience) *to facilitate* makefile recursion.  So the paper might be said "to score an own goal" on that point, at least.

Comment: How do you use include and recursion? If you include a recursive Makefile it isn't going to work correctly since all relative paths will be wrong (unless you always write them from the toplevel which requires manual work when they are run on their own, assuming you want to support that usage).  But if you've managed to make it work and not hit any of the problems good on you.

Comment: @thb I second Etan.  The _only_ time when recursive Make can and should be used, is in the "black box" case.  "Black box" is a software module, that is used by, but does not use, the universe outside of the black box.  Then you can descend to the Black Box and recursively call Make there.  In all other cases, recursive Make simply does not work correctly, period.  It may _appear_ to work, but it is not working correctly.

Comment: As said within the question: »no recursive make calls«

Comment: Yes I know, we were just making an "academic" argument.

Comment: @EtanReisner:  First, I have edited my answer to admit the consensus that my answer is wrong; so thank you for that, and for your good humor during this discussion (good humor having grown less common on StackOverflow than it used to be).  Second, please see my next comment.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Second, in answer to your question, for refactorability (so that I am not maintaining multiple copies of more or less the same rule) I keep most of my make logic in various makefiles and makefile fragments in a "master makefile" subdirectory, then symlink and/or `include` the makefiles and makefile fragments to other directories where needed.  Third, my source tree does not have (or need) an arbitrary structure, but rather all source subdirectories are at the same depth (normally one level) down the tree, so that "../" always refers back to the top-level source directory.

Comment: @MarkGaleck:  Thanks for the interesting second.  It would seem that I still have something to learn about Makefile practice.

Comment: @thb Recursive Make Considered Harmful while it does a good job to explain the basic problem with recursive make, it does not provide a serious alternative.  Here is the paper that does that:  http://evbergen.home.xs4all.nl/nonrecursive-make.html .  I used and extended ideas from this paper on multiple occasions, for several employers and they work very well in a large-scale environment.